# How to subscribe to newly minted blocks?

Tags: web3js, blocks, confirmations

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to poll latest blocks.

I found that there is a `newBlockHeaders` event that I can [subscribe to](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders) using [web3js](/questions/tagged/web3js).

What is not clear to me is how to track the number of confirmations?

The premise of the question is that I want to find an efficient way to get events for a large number of transactions. My thinking is that I need to:

1. Observe and filter `pendingTransactions`
2. Observe `newBlockHeaders`
3. Use `getBlock` to identify all transactions in the block
4. Once I find `pendingTransactions` mentioned in `getBlock`, use `getTransactionReceipt` to find transaction logs.

The question is thus: Is `newBlockHeaders` sufficient for my use case or is it possible that transactions included in block might not have receipt / might not go through?